# solr WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory, remove 0 from digits

Tags: solr

I have this field in my documents:

```
<fieldType name="signature" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>

        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I'm indexing strings like `MUS.F.0594`
and I'm able to search and have correct results for queries like:

```
musf0594 
mus f 0594
mus.f.0594
```

I would like to search also queries like

```
musf594
mus f 594
mus.f.594
```

I need to remove the leading **0** before other digits.
How to do this in the solr index analyzer?

Comment: check by applying the regex "^0+"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by adding the `PatternReplaceFilterFactory`.

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^0+" replacement="" replace="all" />
```

Once you modify the fieldType and reload the collection. You can analyse the fieldType on the solr admin page.

Here is the screenshots from the analysis page.

First Screenshot

[image: Solr analysis page]

Second screenshot

[image: Solr analysis page result]

Comment: `pattern="\.0+"` is better for my need, thanks. however, i would like to have result either with or without `0`, this PatternReplace just remove. 
what is the correct position i should put the filter?

Comment: You can apply the pattern filter factory at the query time as well, then it would work for both the cases..

Comment: i edited the question: i need to have result also for `musf594`, that is the only part that is not working

Comment: I dont think its possible...if you achieve...please do post the answer...You will be able to generate a token musf0594 but not the musf594...To achieve the same you might have to write your own FilterFactory...